# Pod install failed with following error on El Capitan

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods

CocoaPods not working on El Capitan:

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Project Web Viewer`: (``)

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A Moodstocks-iOS-SDK

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing Moodstocks-iOS-SDK (4.1.6)
 > Http download
   $ /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o
   /var/folders/jv/17c1dkr902x7c5_2wmln6n3w0000gn/T/d20160615-44202-kr01v0/file.zip
   https://moodstocks.com/static/releases/moodstocks-ios-sdk-4.1.6.zip --create-dirs
   --netrc
     % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--     0curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

[!] Error installing Moodstocks-iOS-SDK
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/jv/17c1dkr902x7c5_2wmln6n3w0000gn/T/d20160615-44202-kr01v0/file.zip https://moodstocks.com/static/releases/moodstocks-ios-sdk-4.1.6.zip --create-dirs --netrc

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--     0curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found


/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:122:in `rescue in execute_command'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:120:in `execute_command'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:154:in `block in executable'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/http.rb:93:in `download_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/http.rb:26:in `download!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:82:in `block in download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:137:in `block in ui_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:63:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:136:in `ui_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:80:in `download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:103:in `download_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:70:in `download_request'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:170:in `download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:153:in `block in uncached_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:180:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:180:in `in_tmpdir'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:152:in `uncached_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:33:in `download_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:39:in `download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:120:in `download_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:60:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:346:in `install_source_of_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:313:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:84:in `titled_section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:312:in `block in install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:304:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:304:in `install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `block in download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:63:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:158:in `download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:115:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

---

I am not sure which kind of error is this?

FYI, I have updated RubyGems and CocoaPods.

This is my Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Project Web Viewer' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Project Web Viewer
  pod 'Moodstocks-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.1'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It tries to download Moodstock from `https://moodstocks.com/static/releases/moodstocks-ios-sdk-4.1.6.zip`, which currently isn't available (a 404 page is returned).

However, `https://moodstocks.com/static/releases/moodstocks-ios-sdk-4.1.7.zip` seems to exist.

You could try to force that version:

```
pod 'Moodstocks-iOS-SDK', '4.1.7'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'ProjectX' do

pod 'Moodstocks-iOS-SDK'

end
```

This should be your Podfile for the project and it will install the latest Moodstock API version which is 4.1.7. See here on [Cocoapods Page.](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Moodstocks-iOS-SDK)

Answer (score 0):

If pod 'Moodstocks-iOS-SDK', '4.1.7', do not work then please first run

```
$ pod repo update
```

then run

```
$ pod install
```

Note : pod repo update command takes lot of time.